# charAt() not working second time in function for javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function translateWord(n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        if( n.charAt(i).toLowerCase() == "a") {
            return n.charAt(i) = "alpha ";
        } 
    }
}
```

im trying to translate the letter at "i" into alpha but whenever i add the charAt(i) statement it just stops working?

note: im trying to translate the letter at "i" into alpha, not check if it is alpha

for example if i was to write 'aa' i want it to come out as 'alpha alpha'

Comment: `return n.charAt(i) = "alpha ";` Invalid syntax - `=` is assignment.

Comment: return n.charAt(i) == "alpha "; SInlge = is assignment == equality check

Comment: Also charAt returns a char not a string.Why would you compare a char with a string

Comment: What do you want to do? Assignment statement with return clause is an invalid clause...

Comment: Syntax error aside, the return statement would also break out of the loop. So `n.charAt(i)` would only get called once. There's a lot of errors in just 3 lines of code.

Comment: Strings are immutable in JavaScript, you can't assign to `charAt()`. You have to return a *new* string with the changes you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How by doing something like this:

```js
var mystring = "amazon";
mystring = mystring.split('a').join('alpha');
console.log(mystring);
```

Comment: @xaegi Happy to help. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Simple use `String.replace()`

```js
function translateWord(n) {
 return n.replace('a','alpha');
}

console.log(translateWord('man'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1)**

```js
function translateWord(str, word, newWord) {

  var len = 0, newStr = '';

  while (len < str.length) {
    newStr += ( str.charAt(len).toLowerCase() === word ) ? newWord : str[len];
    len++;
  }

  return newStr;

}

console.log(translateWord('Amazon','a','alpha'));
```

**Method 2)**

```js
function translateWord(str) {
 return str.replace(/a/gi,'alpha');
}

console.log(translateWord('Amazon'));
```